# VB.Net - Using reflection to refer to methods outside of classes

Tags: vb.net, reflection, methods, delegates, console

I'm trying to create a program that will execute commands by dynamically invoking methods using the name of a sub provided by the user. With help, I've managed to get it working using a dictionary of strings and Func() or Action() lambda expressions to link to the various subs, but I want to make it so that it will delegate to a sub based on the method name without the need for a separate dictionary.

A structure something like this was suggested in C#:

```
Type type = calcobject.GetType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(RoutineName);
if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(this, ...parameters...);
}
```

Which uses a class of subs and functions. I've managed to get the code working in VB...

```
Dim Params() As String = {3, 4}
Dim Type As Type = GetType(
Dim Method As MethodInfo = Type.GetMethod("Add")
Dim Result As Integer
If Method IsNot Nothing Then
    Result = Method.Invoke(Method, Params)
End If
Console.WriteLine(Result)
```

... but I'd like to use a method that doesn't rely on classes, that can delegate to a method anywhere in the main Module. Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked - but I don't really know what I'm doing. Is there a way I can modify the above code to allow it to refer to a method that isn't in a class?

Comment: The Main module is a class. Just use that.

Comment: Oh, I thought the Main module was the Main module xD. But okay I'll try it.